# How to re-format the javascript object and push it to formgroup in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to reformat the array of object as simplest way and push to formGroup as below. How I can avoid using product word repeatly? Eg: spread operators

```
for (const product of products) {
    this.productArray.push(
        this.fb.group({
            // How to simplify this code
            id: product.product_id, 
            name: product.product_name,
            chargers: product.sales_chargers,
            class: product.class_name,
            price: product.price,
        }),
    );
}
```

Comment: You could name your form controls like your product keys?

Comment: Actually nope. I need assign new key for product info as in code

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry. Point is, if your products keys could match your formcontrol names, you can do this with a single line like this.fbgroup({…product})

Comment: @MikeOne is right. You could have used [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) if your form group keys are same as product keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see formulaic transform from the OP's product keys to the OP's group keys. One alternative is to capture the transformation in data. Then at least, you can define the mapping clearly and know where to go to edit it...

```
const keyMap = { product_id: 'id', product_name: 'name', sales_chargers: 'chargers', class_name: 'class', price: 'price' };
const product2Group = product => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(product).map(([k, v]) => [ keyMap[k] , v ])
);
```

Then, we can replace the OP loop with...

```
this.productArray = products.map(product2Group);
```

Demo...

```js
const keyMap = {
  product_id: 'id',
  product_name: 'name',
  sales_chargers: 'chargers',
  class_name: 'class',
  price: 'price'
};
const product2Group = product => Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(product).map(([k, v]) => [ keyMap[k] , v ])
);

const products = [
  { product_id: 4, product_name: 'my product four', sales_chargers: 'chargers 4', class_name: 'classy class 4', price: 44 },
  { product_id: 5, product_name: 'my product five', sales_chargers: 'chargers 5', class_name: 'classy class 5', price: 55 }
]

const result = products.map(product2Group);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a property, without mentioning the reference. Any solution without `product` is more complicated than Your code.

However you might want to use `.map` to convert each item of the array in a more elegant way.

```
this.productArray = products.map(product =>
    this.fb.group({
        id: product.product_id, 
        name: product.product_name,
        chargers: product.sales_chargers,
        class: product.class_name,
        price: product.price,
    })
)
```

Comment: Thank u @slartidan. It is throwing `Type 'FormGroup[]' is missing the following properties from type 'FormArray'`